# get single record through axios in vuex store

Tags: vuejs2, vuex, nuxt.js, vuex-modules

I would like to return a single record from my back end using a Vuex store module in Nuxt.

I have the following in my component, which passes the value i want 
( which is the $route.params.caseId )

```
created () {
  this.$store.dispatch('cases/getCase', $route.params.caseId );
},
```

I pass the $route.params.caseId into my getCase action in my vuex store module as follows

```
getCase ({ commit, context }, data) {
  return axios.get('http' + data + '.json')
  .then(res => {
    const convertcase = []
    for (const key in res.data) {
      convertcase.push({ ...res.data[key], id: key })
    }
    //console.log(res.data) returns my record from firebase (doesnt display the key though in the array, just the fields within the firebase record, but assume this is expected?

    commit('GET_CASE', convertcase)
  })
  .catch(e => context.error(e));
},
```

the convert case is to extract the id from firebase key and add it to my array as id field (Is this correct for a single result from firebase in this way?)

My mutation

```
// Get Investigation
GET_CASE(state, caseId) {
  state.caseId = caseId;
},
```

Now when I use

Case Name: {{ caseId.case_name }}

I'm not getting any result,

I'm not getting an error though, any thoughts on what i am doing wrong please

Many Thank

Answer (score 0):

You can pass more data to an action like you did in the dispatch method and later access them normally.

Note the data parameter of the getCase function, in your example data === $route.params.caseId

//Load single investigation

```
getCase ({ commit, context }, data) {
  return axios.get('http' + investigationID + '.json')
  .then(res => {
    const convertcase = []
    for (const key in res.data) {
      convertcase.push({ ...res.data[key], id: key })
    }
    commit('GET_CASE', convertcase)
  })
  .catch(e => context.error(e));
},
```

In case you want to use promises, check out the exemple below of a action in my app that fetches a single BLOG_POST

```
let FETCH_BLOG_POST = ({commit, state}, { slug }) => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        fetchBlogPost(slug, state.axios)
        .then((post) => {
            console.log("FETCH_BLOG_POSTS", post.data.data)
            commit('SET_BLOG_POST', post.data.data)
            resolve(post.data)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("FETCH_BLOG_POST.catch")
            reject(error)
        })

    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, half solved my problem but not getting any results, trying first approach first to see if i can get things working, see edit to original question, any idea what my issue is please